# Stop some software from updating in Manjaro

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

I have a lot of software in Manjaro 20.0 that I don't use in my day to day use such as GIMP and Thunderbird (and maybe more) but don't really want to uninstall. Is there some way to temporarily freeze them by excluding them from updates as a lot of them can get really heavy.

I'm looking at saving 200-300mb worth of downloads every week if this were possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to the [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Skip_package_from_being_upgraded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though this might be posted on the wrong forum. I'll try to assist you.
First you would need to edit the pacman configuration file using a text editor of your choice. To do this go into the terminal and type the command `sudo nano /etc/pacman.conf` , once there look for "IgnorePkg" and remove the "#" symbol then add the programs you wish to disable updates for. Once done save the file and exit.

Comment: This worked well in Manjaro  21.3 XFCE edition, running the Linux kernel 5.15 LTS. The package that was failing to build was ceph-libs and now appears in the ignored section of the GUI. Thanks!